# can't import the java files from other directories

Tags: android, class, android-studio, import, package

I almost completed my project and now kind of stuck at the place **where I need to import few java classes to  MainActivity from other directories in android studio**.

I have made 3 packages named app, activity and helper that has got 2 java classes each, but now in src/main/java/MainActivity, I am unable to import them..


I am attaching a screenshot here for you guys, please help.
FYI - I went through few discussions made earlier on kind of similar topic but was unable to resolve my issue, try to be specific, n m sure you will be.

[image]

Comment: Put all packages inside app/src/main/java folder.

Comment: @AnkitaShah I did that as well, its letting me do it even then

Comment: Perfect, its working now !! I did that earlier as well but silly me...wasnt importing it the proper way,

Comment: BTW thanks @AnkitaShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to create different packages inside java folder** and than you will be able to import class from different packages.

**Ex:**

Inside java - create one package, again right click on java and create another package.

Comment: I tried that but while importing it says "cant resolve symbol '<javaclassname>'

Comment: You are probably missing an import statement.

Comment: check import package and verify if it is true path of class

Comment: Its working now ,, thanks @Amit Vaghela , that was my silly mistake, got it right